# database security on the net ; secure access to monitoring servers

Tags: database, security, web-applications, monitoring

I am facing 2 issues before publishing my web application.I have to main questions.

1. How to protect a database publicly accessible on the net ?
2. monitoring servers will also be on the net.

   What is the best secure and flexible way to manage staff's authentications
   on these monitoring servers ? should I use an LDAP system ?
   is it more secure to use another domain name for these servers ?

Thanks in advance for helping me :)

Comment: The way you asking these questions show you have a long way to go. Get some books and read about it, start on programming for the web and then progress to security on the web. Don't publish anything before you finish reading the first one.

Comment: Hi Luis. I am not at all new in programming, but in managing web scale applications. The issue is how to do it securely, knowing that servers I will use will also be on the net

Comment: What I am trying to say is the subject is so broad that it cannot be answered in this medium.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from your question whether you have a public-facing web application that you need to secure, or if you need to secure a publicly accessible database.

If it is the second, I can't really help (not my area of expertise).

If it is the first, you are asking about a fairly complex topic that can't be answered thoroughly in a forum. I would check out the Open Web Application Security Project (http://www.owasp.org) and start reading up. They have a lot of relevant and very detailed information on securing web applications. Specifically, I recommend that you look at their Development Guide ([http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Guide_Project#tab=Downloads](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Guide_Project#tab=Downloads)), it is a great starting point.

Comment: OK. My question seems to be to wide.
You answered to the first question (secure a publicly accessible database) ==> " I can't really help (not my area of expertise)"
The second question is : "should I use another domain name for servers used to monitor my app ?" "should I use an LDAP authentication on these servers to be more flexible ?"

Comment: @Supm4n: Regarding domain name: it's impossible to answer.  An additional domain name is not going to add one bit to any additional security, so it doesn't matter.  As far as LDAP: LDAP isn't any more "flexible" than other security models.